# My program does not work in NSURLConnection before tableView

Tags: ios, xcode, wsdl, nsurlconnection, tableview

Why doesn't my program work in `NSURLConnection` before tableView?

```
//  MyLoxFileTVContoller.m

#import "MyLoxFileTVContoller.h"
#import "xml_myloxfile.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation MyLoxFileTVContoller
@synthesize myloxfileArray;
@synthesize exportId_data_Array,readFG_data_Array,receiverId_data_Array,referenceId_data_Array,referenceName_data_Array,reportFullPath_data_Array,reportName_data_Array,senderId_data_Array,senderName_data_Array,sentDate_data_Array,subject_data_Array; 
@synthesize detailViewController;
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize navigationController;
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize unReadCount;
@synthesize webData;

-(void)doParse{

    NSLog(@"doParse"); //debug

    [myloxfileArray removeAllObjects];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:con=\"http://controller.exportingreportwebservice.lox.org/\">\n"
                             "<soapenv:Header/>\n"
                             "<soapenv:Body>\n"
                             "<con:getReport>\n"
                             "<arg0>%@</arg0>\n"
                             "</con:getReport>\n"
                             "</soapenv:Body>\n"
                             //"</soapenv:Envelope>\n", nameInput.text
                             "</soapenv:Envelope>\n", @"2711"
                             ];
    //NSLog(soapMessage);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://iloxley.loxley.co.th:8081/ExportingReportWebservice/ExportingReportWebservice?wsdl"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        NSLog(@"if theConnection"); //debug
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {

        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }

    NSLog(@"end doParse"); //debug

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"connection didReceiveResponse"); //debug
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"connection didReceiveData"); //debug
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading"); //debug
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"theXML = %@ ", theXML);
    //NSLog(@"webData = %@ ", webData);
    //NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theXML];
    NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];

    // create and init our delegate
    xml_myloxfile_Parser *parser = [[xml_myloxfile_Parser alloc] initXMLParser];

    //set delegate
    [nsXmlParser setDelegate:parser];

    //parsing...
    BOOL success = [nsXmlParser parse];

    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"if success"); //debug

        exportId_data_Array = [parser getExportId_data_Array];
        readFG_data_Array = [parser getReadFG_data_Array];
        receiverId_data_Array = [parser getReceiverId_data_Array];
        referenceId_data_Array = [parser getReferenceId_data_Array];
        referenceName_data_Array = [parser getReferenceName_data_Array];
        reportFullPath_data_Array = [parser getReportFullPath_data_Array];
        reportName_data_Array = [parser getReportName_data_Array];
        senderId_data_Array = [parser getSenderId_data_Array];
        senderName_data_Array = [parser getSenderName_data_Array];
        sentDate_data_Array = [parser getSentDate_data_Array];
        subject_data_Array = [parser getSubject_data_Array];

        items_exportId = exportId_data_Array;
        items_readFG = readFG_data_Array;
        items_receiverId = receiverId_data_Array;
        items_referenceId = referenceId_data_Array;
        items_referenceName = referenceName_data_Array;
        items_reportFullPath = reportFullPath_data_Array;
        items_reportName = reportName_data_Array;
        items_senderId = senderId_data_Array;
        items_senderName = senderName_data_Array;
        items_sentDate = sentDate_data_Array;
        items_subject = subject_data_Array;

        NSLog(@"items_subject = %@ ", items_subject);


    } else {
        NSLog(@"fail");
    }

}

-(void) loadView
{
    NSLog(@"loadView"); //debug
    if (items_subject == nil) {
        //items_subject = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfSectionsInTableView"); //debug
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"tableView numberOfRowsInSection"); //debug
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"[items_subject count] = %d ", [items_subject count]);
    return [items_subject count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath"); //debug
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,[items_subject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //  Populate the cell's detail text label.
    NSString *detailText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"date: %@  from: %@  reference: %@",
                            [[items_sentDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lowercaseString],[[items_senderName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lowercaseString],[[items_referenceName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lowercaseString]];


    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:detailText];

    //CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(10.0, 0.0); 
    //[[cell detailTextLabel] setTransform:translate];

    //unReadCount = 0;

    if([[items_readFG objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"N"]){
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        unReadCount = unReadCount+1;
    }else{
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        unReadCount = unReadCount;
    }

    NSLog(@"unReadCount = %d ",unReadCount);

    //Adding A Badge Number
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:unReadCount];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath"); //debug

    //sof2
    DetailViewController *detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
    [detailController changeExportIdText:[exportId_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [detailController changeReadFGText:[readFG_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [detailController changeReceiverIdText:[receiverId_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [detailController changeReferenceIdText:[referenceId_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [detailController changeReferenceNameText:[referenceName_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [detailController changeReportFullPathText:[reportFullPath_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [detailController changeReportNameText:[reportName_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [detailController changeSenderIdText:[senderId_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [detailController changeSenderNameText:[senderName_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [detailController changeSentDateText:[sentDate_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [detailController changeSubjectText:[subject_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(showItemDetails:)])
    {
        //[delegate showItemDetails:[subject_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [delegate showItemDetails:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@||%@||%@||%@||%@||%@||%@||%@||%@||%@||%@"
                                   ,[exportId_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   ,[readFG_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   ,[receiverId_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   ,[referenceId_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   ,[referenceName_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   ,[reportFullPath_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   ,[reportName_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   ,[senderId_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   ,[senderName_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   ,[sentDate_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   ,[subject_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   ]];//test multi var'
    }

    // Alert will pop up when using Simulator or iPod Touch for example
    /*
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[note_subject_data_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] message:@"Test" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];
     */
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad"); //debug

    [self doParse];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidUnload"); //debug

    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

The log:

```
2012-09-11 15:27:15.377 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] loadView
2012-09-11 15:27:15.378 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] viewDidLoad
2012-09-11 15:27:15.379 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] doParse
2012-09-11 15:27:15.382 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] if theConnection
2012-09-11 15:27:15.382 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] end doParse
2012-09-11 15:27:15.385 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] numberOfSectionsInTableView
2012-09-11 15:27:15.386 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] tableView numberOfRowsInSection
2012-09-11 15:27:15.391 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] [items_subject count] = 0 
2012-09-11 15:27:15.454 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] connection didReceiveResponse
2012-09-11 15:27:15.455 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] connection didReceiveData
2012-09-11 15:27:15.455 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] connectionDidFinishLoading
2012-09-11 15:27:15.455 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] DONE. Received Bytes: 1948
2012-09-11 15:27:15.457 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] if success
2012-09-11 15:27:15.457 MyLoxFile[2698:f803] items_subject = (
    "Surgical Report ",
    "Genotype Report",
    "HPV Report"
)
```

It has data in array but not have in tableView `numberOfRowsInSection`

Before this code i use XML (not WSDL) it's work

This is My Code -> http://www.vasuta.com/ios/MyLoxFile.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your tableview is load et call its delegates methods before your NSURLConnection finished downloading. 
You have launch NSURLConnection by

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

so the connection is asynchronous. You can't be sure whether it finishes before or after your tableview loads its view.
But your can always do a check in your tableview methods to make your app work. For example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int nbCount = [items_subject count];
    if (nbCount == 0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return [items_subject count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int nbCount = [items_subject count];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (nbCount ==0)
        cell.textLabel.text == @"Loading";
    else
    {
        // your configuration
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,[items_subject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    return cell;
 }
```

In your method "ConnectionDidFinishLoading", then your can call [tableview reloaddata] to update your tableview.

[EDIT] on 12/09/2012

I've got your code work(not a nice solution), you should rethink how you organize your viewControllers.

1. add the IBOutlet TableView to myloxfileController.tableView.
   add this line `myloxfileContoller.tableView = myloxfileTable;` after the line `myloxfileContoller.view = myloxfileContoller.tableView;` in `- (void)viewDidLoad` of the interface `ViewController` .
2. reload tableview data when connection finished.
   add this line `[self.tableView reloadData];` after the line `items_subject = subject_data_Array;` in `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` of the interface `MyLoxFileTVController` .

This will work because when the download finished, you reloadData of the IBOutlet TableView.

Comment: when i use [tableview reloaddata] ... it's load data non stop and not display in tableview

Comment: what do you mean by "load data non stop"?

Comment: sorry for my english skill -_- ... i don't know how i can talk to you ... if you load my app' and put [salf.tableview reloaddata] in code and run ... you can see in log.

Comment: we can't run you app, because we don't have all your libraries. You must tell us exactly what's going on and what you've tried. You know, that's why people don't think your question is well formulated(-3 votes).

Comment: sorry for my question sorry for my english skill sorry for my ios skills .... thank Sisi ....

Comment: I can't get it work because of connection error. But I've got it work by using another url. Your structure of views and controllers is really bizarre. You have a tableview owned by ViewController. But you use another MyFoxFileTVController who doesn't own it to control it. I don't think it's the best way to do it. Rethink the hierarchy. I'll post my solution(not nice but work) in an answer.

Comment: you can accress this url http://iloxley.loxley.co.th:8081/ExportingReportWebservice/ExportingReportWebservice?wsdl ... thank Sisi

Comment: I've modified my answer. Look at [EDIT] of this answer. See if it work for you

Comment: Oh ... it's work for me ... thankyou very much Sisi ... when i add [self.tableView reloadData]; only it's not work ... but when i add myloxfileContoller.tableView = myloxfileTable; ..... it's work ...... thank thank thank Sisi .....

Answer (score 0):

Have you used [uitableview reloadData] after updating your NSArray?

Comment: yes i use [self.tableView reloadData]; after update array but it not work -_-

Answer (score 0):

replace with

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"tableView numberOfRowsInSection"); //debug
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"[items_subject count] = %@ ", [items_subject count]);
    return [items_subject count];
}
```